# Vending Machine Program (Help)

Tags: c++

at the moment I am trying to write a vending machine program and I seem to be having two logical errors that I can't figure out. First, when I try and select a different product for my vending machine program it always selects the first product and I do not know why. Second, I tried to make an exit condition that allows the user to exit the program at anytime but the program always ends after I ask the user no matter what. Below is my code:

```
//Vending Machine Program
#include <iostream>;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double product1 = 59.99;
    double product2 = 59.99;
    double product3 = 59.99;
    double product4 = 59.99;
    double customerMoney = 0.00;

    cout << "How much money do you have? ";
    cin >> customerMoney;

    while (customerMoney >= 59.99)
    {
        int customerChoice = 0;
        //bool exitProgram;

        cout << "Which product would you like to buy?\n Enter '1' for Killzone: Shadow Fall ($59.99)\n Enter '2' for Deadrising 3 ($59.99)\n Enter '3' for Call of Duty Ghosts ($59.99)\n Enter '4' for Madden NFL 25 ($59.99)";
        cin >> customerChoice;
        if (customerChoice = 1)
        {
            cout << "You have selected Killzone: Shadow Fall\n";
            customerMoney = customerMoney - product1;
            cout << "You have $" << customerMoney << " left\n";

            /*cout << "Would you like to exit the program? (Enter '1' for true and '0' for false)";
            cin >> exitProgram;
            if (exitProgram = 1)
            {
                return 0;
            }*/
        }
        else if (customerChoice = 2)
        {
            cout << "You have selected Deadrising 3\n";
            customerMoney = customerMoney - product2;
            cout << "You have $" << customerMoney << " left\n";

            /*cout << "Would you like to exit the program? (Enter '1' for true and '0' for false)";
            cin >> exitProgram;
            if (exitProgram = 1)
            {
            return 0;
            }*/
        }
        else if (customerChoice = 3)
        {
            cout << "You have selected Call of Duty Ghosts\n";
            customerMoney = customerMoney - product3;
            cout << "You have $" << customerMoney << " left\n";

            /*cout << "Would you like to exit the program? (Enter '1' for true and '0' for false)";
            cin >> exitProgram;
            if (exitProgram = 1)
            {
            return 0;
            }*/
        }
        else if (customerChoice = 4)
        {
            cout << "You have selected Madden NFL 25\n";
            customerMoney = customerMoney - product4;
            cout << "You have $" << customerMoney << " left\n";

            /*cout << "Would you like to exit the program? (Enter '1' for true and '0' for false)";
            cin >> exitProgram;
            if (exitProgram = 1)
            {
            return 0;
            }*/
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "You don't have enough money to purchase anything else. Thank you for shopping!";
        }
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've rolled back  your edit, which was inappropriate. If you now have a new question, create a new post and ask it there. It's not proper behavior to totally change the content of a question once you've received an answer to it; the change makes existing answers incorrect, and can cause the posters to receive downvotes. It's also totally rude to them after they spent time giving you free help for your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (customerChoice = 1)
```

You are using "=" which is an assigment. You need "=="

```
if (customerChoice == 1)
```

The reason this did not throw a compile error is that technically an assigment does return a value. In fact, in your case the return value of assigning 1 to customerChoice will be 1, which will evaluate to True in the if statement.